# Getting Exception While Reading the Excel 2013 version file through the XML Reader using JAVA

Tags: java, excel, xml

```
(javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException) javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[2,1062]
Message: Attribute name "verorksheet" associated with an element type "pageSetup" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
```

This is only happening with EXCEL 2013. The code works with all other versions. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: You might want to consider adding a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code.

Comment: If it is .xlsx unzip it. The error is on line 2, column 1062. I expect `pageSetup[linebreak]=` or such. Such things can be patched by a wrapping InputStream or whatever.

Comment: Sure Iam Adding My sample Code and thanks for the Reply.package